# Problems with tensorflow_hub in google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to play with BERT in Google Colab and

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

but it raising ValueError:

```
The name 'tf.TrackableConstant' has already been registered to a serializable class. Found: <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.function_saved_model_utils.TrackableConstant'>
```

I believe It's a version conflict or smth like that, but can't fix it.
I've already tried restarting the environment, installing different versions of tensorflow and tensorflow_hub etc., but it didn't work.

Comment: It's working fine for me. `import tensorflow_hub as hub;
hub.version.__version__ ; # 0.12.0` what else are you doing in that notebook? Maybe try a fresh colab runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with 2.9.2 but worked fine when I downgraded to 2.7

Answer (score 0):

`Tensorflow_hub` is working fine and not showing any error when I tried replicating the same in `Google Colab`.(Please check the image below). I have also replicated this [Classify text with BERT mdoel](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert) in Google colab which is working as expected.

Could you please try again and let us know if the issue still persists.

[image]